# On macOS Sierra Airplay is always "Looking for Apple TV"

Tags: display, appletv, macos, airplay, preferences

Just upgraded to macOS 10.12.1 Sierra and the mirroring display options keeps oscillating between: "Looking for Apple TV" and "Off".

In preferences i have turned AirPlay Off. But it keeps looking for AppleTV.
As recommended in an earlier discussion i tried:

```
sudo chmod 000 /System/Library/CoreServices/AirPlayUIAgent.app/Contents/MacOS/AirPlayUIAgent
```

but it gave an error:

```
chmod: Unable to change file mode on AirPlayUIAgent: Operation not permitted
```

It looks like Sierra always wants to keep connecting to Apple TV - big nuisance. Any other ideas to turn this auto feature off?

Comment: Can you reference this "earlier discussion" by giving the source?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/255662/37413 except I don't know if the other person had some problem with it always trying to connect with something or just wanted it disabled for other reasons.

Comment: I have this issue with High Sierra when I have bluetooth enabled.  Turning bluetooth off made the Mirror Display options icon disappear from the menu bar.  It is uncertain if that fixed the problem (i.e. stopped my Mac from searching for an Apple TV source) or just takes away the indicator.  If Apple TV runs over bluetooth, then this is a lame fix.  However, there are times where I would like to have bluetooth on, but no searching for Apple TV.  So, this is not ideal.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue. It started occurring when my external speaker tried automatically connecting to the device. Turning off bluetooth entirely solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -2):

You could just reboot your Bluetooth.